# Challenges in Developing AI Algorithms for X-ray Image Analysis on Large Datasets

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, image-recognition, agi, image-processing

```
Hello everyone,
```

- I'm currently working on a research project involving X-ray imaging
  and the development of AI algorithms to detect diseases from large
  representative datasets. I wanted to reach out to the community to
  discuss some of the challenges I've encountered and see if anyone has
  insights or suggestions.
- I've been experimenting with various deep learning architectures,
  such as convolutional neural networks (CNNs), for    disease
  detection. While they've shown promise, I'm curious about any
  recent breakthroughs or improvements in network architectures
  specifically designed for medical image analysis.
  I am currently looking for some interesting researchable areas of study for a PhD in AI for medical imaging.

  **I appreciate any input, experiences, or advice you can share**.

Comment: it's not clear what's your current understanding of the architectures, what topic of CV you are interested, if segmentation, explainability, classification or what, your question is way to vague

Comment: I performed classification and I also want to do explainability.